# Remove the max value from an array in a document

Tags: mongodb

Using mongodb. I have a collection of vehicles, each one has an array of accidents, and each accident has a date.

```
Vehicle {
  _id: ...,,
  GasAMount...,
  Type: ...,
  Accidents: [
   {
      Date: ISODate(...),
      Type: ..,
      Cost: ..
   },
   {
      Date: ISODate(..),
      Type: ..,
      Cost:...,
   }
  ]
}
```

How can i remove the oldest accident of each vehicle without using aggregate ?
Important not to use the aggregate method.

Comment: This smells like homework.. Please make clear what you have already tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you may have to use aggregation in this case as it's near impossible to find a non-aggregation based solution that can be as efficient.
Aggregation is useful here to get the embedded documents with the oldest date. Once you get them it's easier to do an update. The following demonstrates this concept, using MongoDB's **[bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.updateOne/#Bulk.find.updateOne)** to update your collection:

```
var bulk = db.vehicles.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0,    
    pipeline = [
        { "$unwind": "$Accidents" },
        { 
            "$group": { 
                "_id": "$_id",
                "oldestDate": { "$min": "$Accidents.Date" }
            } 
        }       
    ];

var cur = db.vehicles.aggregate(pipeline);

cur.forEach(function (doc){
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$pull": { "Accidents": { "Date": doc.oldestDate } }
    });

    counter++;

    if (counter % 100 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.vehicles.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 100 != 0) bulk.execute();
```